# theme style is applied on the dhasboard rather than the website

Tags: theme-development, themes, css, wp-enqueue-style

I am creating a new theme, I created a new directory called **mytheme** and created three files directly inside the directory where the content is as follow:
**index.php**

```
<?php echo "hellow world"; ?>
```

**style.css**

```
/*
Theme Name: mytheme
*/
body {background: red;}
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php
wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
?>
```

the problem: the dashboard is colored in red.
expectations: the website itself to be colored in red.

**Edit:**
the solution marked is only half the answer.
**index.php**  needs to have headers initiated otherwise it wont work
**index.php** is now:

```
<?php
wp_header();
echo "hellow world";
?>
```

Comment: You're supposed to enqueue things on a particular hook, WordPress will have filled your PHP error log with warnings about this

Comment: Thank you so much, am following the official themes development handbook. There was no mention for any action hook. But will check. Thank you

Comment: You need to use `get_header()` and `get_footer()` in all template files apart from `index.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enqueue your stylesheets and script to `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook.

In your functions.php try

```
function enqueue_scripts_cp() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
} 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts_cp' );
```

Comment: I used wp_enqueue_scripts action hook and didnt work, in fact I even copy pasted your code. is it tested ? does it work in your end ?